# why val not affect to the array in KOTLIN?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

```
fun main(args:Array<String>)
{
    val num:Int=6
    //  num=10 if I initialize like this it will error
    val arr=Array<Int>(5){0}
    arr[0]=5  //when I initialize like this it not error 
}
```

//Please tell me why it is not error

Comment: You cannot mutate the `arr` variable, but you can mutate the array it points to. An array is always mutable.

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin `val` means "read only", i.e. the setter for that property won't be generated. That means that you cannot reassign `arr`, but you can still mutate its content.

That is the difference between immutability (you wouldn't be able to change the array content) and read-only (you cannot reassign the variable).

Example:

```
val readOnly = arrayListOf<Int>()
readOnly.add(1) // OK
readOnly = arrayListOf() // compilation error

val immutable = Collections.unmodifiableList(arrayListOf(1))
immutable[0] = 2 // throws exception at runtime

val anotherImmutable = listOf(1)
anotherImmutable[0] = 2 // compilation error
```

Comment: In Kotlin you have immutable lists with compile-time safety. You can use `listOf(1)` and the resulting `List` won't even have the `set(index: Int, element: E)` operator